# Name for a verb form meaning "feign or pretend to do sth"

Tags: terminology, verbs, derivation

Is there an accepted name for a derivational process applied to a verb which conveys the meaning "feign or pretend to do sth".

As a corollary, is anyone aware of any languages (especially non-polysynthetic ones) that possess such a derivational process (e.g. using an affix)?

I do know of one already, Iñupiatun Eskimo, in which the affix *-ŋŋuaq-* does this, cf. the full verb stem *piŋŋuaq-* (Seiler 2012: *s.vv.*):

> Qichaq atu**ŋŋuaq**tuq.
>
> Qichaq pretends to sing.

However, Iñupiatun Eskimo has such a huge number of derivational affixes that it is a different kind of animal to less extremely polysynthetic languages.

**Reference:**
Seiler, Wolf A. 2012. *Iñupiatun Eskimo Dictionary* (Language and Culture Documentation and Description 16). SIL International.

Comment: This is one of the functions of the Dt stem in at least Biblical Hebrew, I can have a look later for the technical term used in the relevant reference grammar.

Answer (score 7):

As I wrote in a comment, this is one of the functions of the Biblical Hebrew Dt (hitpael) stem, but the two reference grammars I had a look at do not agree on terminology:

- Waltke and O'Connor (An Introduction to Biblical Hebrew Syntax, §26.2f):

  > The *estimative-declarative reflexive* is the counterpart to the *Piel*'s use to esteem someone as in a state or to declare someone as existing in a state; the *Hithpael* may denote esteeming or presenting oneself in a state, sometimes without regard to the question of truthfulness.
- Joüon and Muraoka (A Grammar of Biblical Hebrew<sup>2</sup>, §53i):

  > [The hitpael] sometimes has the "simulating" nuance of *to disguise oneself as* or *to show oneself* (truly or falsely) *to be such and such*.

Examples (taken from both) include pretending to be ill (2 Samuel 13:5,6), feigning to be a mourner (2 Samuel 14:2); acting like a drunkard (1 Samuel 1:14); pretending to be rich (Proverbs 13:7).

So we have the terms "estimative-declarative reflexive" and "simulating nuance". Perhaps scholars of this language don't need a widespread term because the meaning is rather transparent (it is a combination of that of the factitive/declarative D stem and the reflexive *t* infix).

Answer (score 2):

I recently found some literature on this function in Wolof referred to as the "pretendive" (though I'm not sure how standard a term that is):

- Torrence, Harold. 2013. *The Clause Structure of Wolof: Insights Into the Left Periphery* (Linguistik Aktuell/Linguistics Today 198). Amsterdam: John Benjamins.
- Tamba, Khady. 2014. *Clausal nominalization in Wolof*. PhD thesis, University of Kansas.